# How can I use Google wallet without opening a webview

Tags: android, payment, android-pay

I want the google wallet payment to be inside the app.

I found this but it doesnt help: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

Example:

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That's an in app purchase.

Comment: well, how can I do it then? @Lesleh

Answer (score 2):

[In-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) is covered on the Android developer site.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful - go to https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/ and scroll down to section "Which API should you use?" 
You can start here to see which API is suitable to your use case as @Lesleh pointed out if you are selling Digital Goods from Android app then In-App-Billing (linked from the same page) is your answer. Whereas if you are selling Physical goods from Android apps then look at Google Wallet Instant Buy API (again linked from the same page).